# Isolated points of set

Tags: real-analysis

For a set $S \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $S^{\bullet} = \{x \in S: \text{x is not limit point of S}\}$ (i.e. $S^{\bullet}$ is the set of all isolated points of $S$). Prove or disprove the following:
(a) For every $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\bar {A^{0}} = \bar {A}$
(b) For every $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $(A^{\bullet})^{\bullet} = A^{\bullet}$
(c) Define sequence of subsets $A_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_k \setminus A_k' =\emptyset$. Then, $B = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ satisfies $B\setminus B' = \emptyset$

I can't think of any counterexample nor can't prove any of them. Any help is appreciated :) !

Comment: I've replaced `S^.` with `S^\bullet` as the full-stop was barely visible

Comment: Please note $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ or $A\in P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but not $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

(a) False. Simply find a non-empty set with no inner points. This should be doable.

(b) True. You should prove that if $B\subset A$ and $x\in B$, $x$ is a limit point in $B$ implies it is a limit point of $A$. This means that if $x\in A^\bullet$ is a limit point in $A^\bullet$, it would be a limit point of $A$, and thus it cannot lie in $A^\bullet$ as we removed all limit points, contradiction. Thus $A^\bullet$ has no limit points, and gives the desired identity.

(c) True. Take any point $x\in B$. Then $x\in A_i$ for all $i$, and this implies $x\in A_i'$ for all $i$. Then $x\in B'$, and so we see $B\subset B'$, i.e. $B\setminus B'=\emptyset$.

Comment: the reason x∈A′i  for all i. Then x∈B′,?

Comment: I am assuming you define $B'=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty  A_k'$, no? Then this is by definition.